# Flutter how to make this class return onChanged?

Tags: class, flutter, listview, dart

I used some classes online to edit them and make what I needed, this is what I got, however I need to get the data using an 'onChange' function, so I can use it in different forms in the app.

How would I be able to do it? This is the code of the class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sembast/sembast.dart';

import 'flutter_search_pannel/flutter_search_panel.dart';
import 'flutter_search_pannel/search_item.dart';

class SuspendedListPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  SuspendedListPicker({
    this.data,
    this.onChanged,
  });

  List<SearchItem<int>> data = [];
  final Function onChanged;

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState(data);
}

class _MyAppState extends State<SuspendedListPicker> {
  _MyAppState(this.data);
  List<SearchItem<int>> data = [];
  var selected;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.55,
        child: FlutterSearchPanel<int>(
          title: "Selecione",
          data: data,

          //padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          icon: Icon(Icons.label, color: Colors.blue[300]),
          color: Colors.white,

          textStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 28.0,
            // onChanged: (value) {
            //   print(value);
            // },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

And here is Flutter_search_panel asset that I also modified (It is an import from https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_search_panel)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'search_page.dart';
import 'search_item.dart';

class FlutterSearchPanel<TValue> extends StatefulWidget {
  @required
  final Function onChanged;
  @required
  final List<SearchItem<TValue>> data;
  final String title;
  final Icon icon;
  final TextStyle textStyle;
  final Color color;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;
  final TValue selected;

  FlutterSearchPanel(
      {this.onChanged,
      this.title,
      this.data,
      this.icon,
      this.textStyle,
      this.selected,
      this.padding,
      this.color});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _FlutterSearchPanelState<TValue>();
  }
}

class _FlutterSearchPanelState<TValue>
    extends State<FlutterSearchPanel<TValue>> {
  SearchItem<TValue> selection;
  final _defaultIcon = Icons.label;
  final TextStyle _defaultTextStyle =
      new TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 22.0);
  final Color _defaultColor = Colors.red;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry _defaultPadding = EdgeInsets.all(10.0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.selected != null) {
      selection = widget.data.firstWhere(
          (item) => item.value == widget.selected,
          orElse: () => selection = widget.data[0]);
    } else {
      selection = widget.data[0];
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  _openSearchPage() async {
    final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SearchPage(
              title: widget.title,
              data: widget.data,
              icon: widget.icon ?? _defaultIcon,
              padding: widget.padding ?? _defaultPadding,
              color: widget.color ?? _defaultColor,
              textStyle: widget.textStyle ?? _defaultTextStyle)),
    );

    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        selection = result;
      });
      if (widget.onChanged != null) {
        widget.onChanged((result as SearchItem<TValue>).value);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new InkWell(
    onTap: _openSearchPage,
    child: SizedBox(
    //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
            child: Text(
                selection.text,

                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                style: widget.textStyle ?? Theme.of(context).textTheme.button, 
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
}


// RaisedButton(
//         color: widget.color ?? Colors.blue,
//         child: Flex(
//           direction: Axis.horizontal,
//           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
//           children: <Widget>[
//             Flexible(
//               child: Padding(
//                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
//                 child: Text(
//                   selection.text,
//                   style: widget.textStyle ?? Theme.of(context).textTheme.button, textAlign: TextAlign.right,
//                 ),
//               ),
//             ),
//           ],
//         ),
//         padding: widget.padding,
//         onPressed: _openSearchPage,
//       );
```

Comment: That list of searchitem<int>, where does it come from?

Comment: flutter search panel, lemme update with the asset that I also had to modify but the import is from there

Comment: Basically, the value will be the selection made by the user.  You can then just set the onchanged property to your onchanged function passing in the value.  onChanged: (value) => onChanged(value).  Make sure to accept the value as the type in the parameters for your onChanged souce.  Btw, your data property is set both in your Widget and State classes.  Remove the one in your state class, since it is passed in your widget constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can in `onChanged` call `widget.onChanged(value)` 
And define a variable `currentValue` to receive this `value` 
code snippet

```
class _SuspendedListPickerState extends State<SuspendedListPicker> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.55,
        child: FlutterSearchPanel<int>(
          title: "Selecione",
          data: widget.data,
          //padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          icon: Icon(Icons.label, color: Colors.blue[300]),
          color: Colors.white,
          textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 28.0),
          onChanged: (value) {
            widget.onChanged(value);
          },
        ));
  }
}
...
int currentValue;
...
SuspendedListPicker(
  data: data,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      currentValue = value;
    });
  },
),
Text('current value $currentValue'),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchItem<TValue> {
  /// Item value
  final TValue value;

  /// Item display text
  final String text;

  SearchItem(this.value, this.text);
}

class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<SearchItem> data;
  final Icon icon;
  final TextStyle textStyle;
  final Color color;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;
  final String title;

  SearchPage(
      {this.data,
      this.icon,
      this.textStyle,
      this.padding,
      this.color,
      this.title});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _SearchPageState();
  }
}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
  List<SearchItem> _searchList = [];

  List<SearchItem> _dataList = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dataList = widget.data;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _searchList.clear();
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _onChange(SearchItem selection) {
    Navigator.pop(context, selection);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: widget.color,
        title: new Text(widget.title ?? 'Search Page'),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            color: widget.color,
            child: new Padding(
              padding: widget.padding,
              child: new Card(
                child: new ListTile(
                  leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
                  title: new TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Search', border: InputBorder.none),
                    onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,
                  ),
                  trailing: new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.cancel),
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.clear();
                      onSearchTextChanged('');
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Expanded(
            child: _searchList.length != 0 || controller.text.isNotEmpty
                ? new ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _searchList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      return new Card(
                        color: widget.color,
                        child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context, _searchList[i]);
                          },
                          child: new ListTile(
                            leading: widget.icon,
                            title: new Text(_searchList[i].text,
                                style: widget.textStyle),
                          ),
                        ),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      );
                    },
                  )
                : new ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _dataList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return new Card(
                        color: widget.color,
                        child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _onChange(_dataList[index]);
                            },
                            child: new ListTile(
                              leading: widget.icon,
                              title: new Text(
                                _dataList[index].text,
                                style: widget.textStyle,
                              ),
                            )),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
    _searchList.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {});
      return;
    }

    _dataList.forEach((userDetail) {
      if (userDetail.text.startsWith(text.toLowerCase()) ||
          userDetail.text.toLowerCase().startsWith(
              text.toLowerCase())) if (_searchList.contains(userDetail) ==
          false) {
        _searchList.add(userDetail);
      }
    });

    setState(() {});
  }
}

class FlutterSearchPanel<TValue> extends StatefulWidget {
  @required
  final Function onChanged;
  @required
  final List<SearchItem<TValue>> data;
  final String title;
  final Icon icon;
  final TextStyle textStyle;
  final Color color;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;
  final TValue selected;

  FlutterSearchPanel(
      {this.onChanged,
      this.title,
      this.data,
      this.icon,
      this.textStyle,
      this.selected,
      this.padding,
      this.color});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _FlutterSearchPanelState<TValue>();
  }
}

class _FlutterSearchPanelState<TValue>
    extends State<FlutterSearchPanel<TValue>> {
  SearchItem<TValue> selection;
  final _defaultIcon = Icons.label;
  final TextStyle _defaultTextStyle =
      new TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 22.0);
  final Color _defaultColor = Colors.red;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry _defaultPadding = EdgeInsets.all(10.0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.selected != null) {
      selection = widget.data.firstWhere(
          (item) => item.value == widget.selected,
          orElse: () => selection = widget.data[0]);
    } else {
      selection = widget.data[0];
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  _openSearchPage() async {
    final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SearchPage(
              title: widget.title,
              data: widget.data,
              icon: widget.icon ?? _defaultIcon,
              padding: widget.padding ?? _defaultPadding,
              color: widget.color ?? _defaultColor,
              textStyle: widget.textStyle ?? _defaultTextStyle)),
    );

    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        selection = result;
      });
      if (widget.onChanged != null) {
        widget.onChanged((result as SearchItem<TValue>).value);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new InkWell(
        onTap: _openSearchPage,
        child: SizedBox(
          //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
            child: Text(
              selection.text,
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              style: widget.textStyle ?? Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class SuspendedListPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  SuspendedListPicker({
    Key key,
    this.data,
    this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  List<SearchItem<int>> data = [];
  final Function onChanged;

  @override
  _SuspendedListPickerState createState() => _SuspendedListPickerState();
}

class _SuspendedListPickerState extends State<SuspendedListPicker> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.55,
        child: FlutterSearchPanel<int>(
          title: "Selecione",
          data: widget.data,
          //padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          icon: Icon(Icons.label, color: Colors.blue[300]),
          color: Colors.white,
          textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 28.0),
          onChanged: (value) {
            widget.onChanged(value);
          },
        ));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int currentValue;
  List<SearchItem<int>> data = [
    SearchItem(0, 'This'),
    SearchItem(1, 'is'),
    SearchItem(2, 'a'),
    SearchItem(3, 'test'),
    SearchItem(4, '.'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SuspendedListPicker(
              data: data,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  currentValue = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            Text('current value $currentValue'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```